# Matching pairs using Linux terminal

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file named list.txt containing a (supplier,product) pair and I must show the number of products from every supplier and their names using Linux terminal

Sample input:

```
stationery:paper
grocery:apples
grocery:pears
dairy:milk
stationery:pen
dairy:cheese
stationery:rubber
```

And the result should be something like:

```
stationery: 3
stationery: paper pen rubber
grocery: 2
grocery: apples pears
dairy: 2
dairy: milk cheese
```

Comment: `how to approach this` - with an `awk` script. Take a course and learn awk scripting, there are many online examples available. Then read the input into associative array indexed by first column - one array for storing the result and a second array of counts. Then output both arrays in `END` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pipeline shoud do the job

```
< your_input_file sort -t: -k1,1r | sort -t: -k1,1r | sed -E -n ':a;$p;N;s/([^:]*): *(.*)\n\1:/\1: \2 /;ta;P;D' | awk -F' ' '{ print $1, NF-1; print $0 }'
```

where

- `sort` sorts the lines according to what's before the colon, in order to ease the successive processing
- the cryptic `sed` joins the lines with common supplier
- `awk` counts the items for supplier and prints everything appropriately.

Doing it with `awk` only, as suggested by KamilCuk in a comment, would be a **much easier** job; doing it with `sed` only would be (for me) a nightmare. Using both is maybe silly, but I enjoyed doing it.

If you need a detailed explanation, please comment, and I'll find time to provide one.

Here's the `sed` script written one command per line:

```
:a
$p
N
s/([^:]*): *(.*)\n\1:/\1: \2 /
ta
P
D
```

and here's how it works:

1. `:a` is just a label where we can jump back through a `t`est or `b`ranch command;
2. `$p` is the `p`rint command applied only to the address `$` (the last line); note that all other commands are applied to every line, since no address is specified;
3. `N` read one more line and appends it to the current pattern space, putting a `\n`ewline in between; this creates a multiline in the pattern space
4. `s/([^:]*): *(.*)\n\1:/\1: \2 /` captures what's before the first colon on the line, `([^:]*)`, as well as what follows it, `(.*)`, getting rid of eccessive spaces, `*`;
5. `ta` `t`ests if the previous `s` command was successful, and, if this is the case, transfers the control to the line labelled by `a` (i.e. go to step 1);
6. `P` prints the leading part of the multiline up to and including the embedded `\n`ewline;
7. `D` deletes the leading part of the multiline up to and including the embedded `\n`ewline.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe this actually worked, but I doubt I will ever memorize this thing haha. Awk-only method seems easier / or trying to work with some associative array. But I don't know yet how to print every supplier from the file, I can do only one by writing awk '/dairy/ {print $3}' file.txt

Comment: @SADBOYS, I've given a quick explanation of how the `sed` command works. Please, let me know if it clear. Besides, fyi, I've also added an [`awk`-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60592320/5825294).

Answer (score 2):

Save the input to *file*, and remove the empty lines.  Then use [*GNU* `datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/):

```
datamash -s -t ':'  groupby 1  count 2  unique 2  < file
```

Output:

```
dairy:2:cheese,milk
grocery:2:apples,pears
stationery:3:paper,pen,rubber
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be close to the only `awk` code I was referring to:

```
< os awk -F: '{ count[$1] += 1; items[$1] = items[$1] " " $2 } END { for (supp in items) print supp": " count[supp], "\n"supp":" items[supp]}'
```

The `awk` script is more readable if written on several lines:

```
awk -F: '{ # for each line
  # we use the word before the : as the key of an associative array
  count[$1] += 1               # increment the count for the given supplier
  items[$1] = items[$1] " " $2 # concatenate the current item to the previous ones
}
END { # after processing the whole file
      for (supp in items) # iterate on the suppliers and print the result
        print supp": " count[supp], "\n"supp":" items[supp]
    }
```